# How to append to multidimensional array in a smarty template?

Tags: arrays, templates, multidimensional-array, smarty, smarty3

I can append to a single array using

```
{append var='name' value='Bob' index='first'}
```

However, if I have a multi-dimensional array such as:

```
$name[first][last] = ['this','array']
```

and I want to append another value to the array at `$name[first][last]` e.g. to make the array like this:

```
$name[first][last] = ['this','array','appended']
```

how can I do this in the smarty template?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without using `append`:

```
{$name[first][last][] = 'this'}
{$name[first][last][] = 'array'}
{$name[first][last][] = 'appended'}
```

I must highlight though - templates should be used for specific purpose: to display prepared data; having to do the above is a code smell

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! Search for complex solution and it's so easy...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested many cases to try achieve it and I think it's not possible (in documentation there is also no info or example of multidimensional key or var)

You should also really think do you need it at all. Logic should be in PHP and role of Smarty is only displaying data not manipulating them